# moving a file from ntfs to btrfs while preserving the creation time

Tags: filesystems, btrfs, ntfs

Both `ntfs` and `btrfs` support file creation times. When I copy a file however, only the modification time is preserved.

Is there a way to preserve creation times too?

For context I wish to migrate my entire partition from `ntfs` to `btrfs`, and it would be nice to preserve the creation times.

PS.

When I move a file from `btrfs` to `btrfs` itself all the dates are the same, which is what I would like to do for `ntfs` to `btrfs` as well. The dates here include the access, modify, create dates on `btrfs`.

Comment: Did you tried `cp -p`? See https://superuser.com/a/114198.

Comment: @AntonLeontiev Yes I did, the creation times is set to the current time when I use that. Only the access & modify times are copied correctly.

Comment: since `creation time` timestamps aren't standard, you'll probably have to code up a custom tool that reads the creation time on the source filesystem, copies the file, and then sets the creation time on the destination filesystem.  `ctime`, which you see with `stat`, is not "creation time", it is "change time", and it refers to file metadata.  if you `chown` or `chmod` a file, for example, that will update the `ctime` timestamp.

Comment: @TimKennedy Yes that would be my last resort. I know `ctime` is change time, but on btrfs has support of actual creation time, stored as `otime`. It would be great if there were some tools to ease the job instead of coding something from scratch.